# $(".class").on is not a function - jQuery error

Tags: jquery, html, video

I'm new to Javascript/jQuery and I'm trying to make a play button for HTML5 video play back.
My code so far:

```
//return a jQuery object
var video = $('#myVideoTag');

//Play/Pause control clicked

$('.btnPlay').on('click', function() {
   if(video[0].paused) {
      video[0].play();
   }
   else {
      video[0].pause();
   }
   return false;
});
```

I keep getting this error:

```
$(".btnPlay").on is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$('.btnPlay').on('click', function() {
```

I can't for the life of my figure out what is wrong. I have the class .btnPlay properly defined on the page. I'm following a tutorial that seems to use an identical method with no issues. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was introduced in jQuery version 1.7.

I think you have to upgrade your jQuery library to the [newest version](http://jquery.com/download/).

Otherwise, you can use [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
$('.btnPlay').bind("click", function() {
    // ...
});
```

or its shortcut method [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

```
$('.btnPlay').click(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As of **jQuery 1.7**, [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) has been superseded by the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event **delegation** `.delegate()`.

An other alternative is the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) but since version 1.7 is deprecated. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the .on method on older versions of javascript is .delegate. You should use `.delegate('.btnPlay', 'click', function(){...})` on the parent element to have the same functionality